# Finding a minimal subset of strings whose bitwise OR is the all ones string

Tags: algorithms

Consider we're given a set $S\subset \{0,1\}^n$ and we want to find a minimal subset $A \subset S$ under the property that if we bitwise OR all of the strings in $A$ we get the all ones string $1^n$. I have been having trouble finding a polynomial time algorithm for this or finding evidence that one doesn't exist (e.g.- by showing this problem to be NP-Complete). Does anyone have any ideas or references which may help answer my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [set cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem), a well-known NP-complete problem, in disguise.

Comment: And here I was formulating it as an integer programming problem